# Latex Missing $ Help

Tags: errors

```
How much glucose $(C_6H_{12}O_6)$ per liter should be used for an intravenous solution
to match the $7.65$ atm at $37 °C$ osmotic pressure of blood?
```

What's wrong with this LaTeX Code? I can't figure it out, it says missing $ inserted.

Comment: I guess its the °. Try ^\circ instead.

Answer (score 7):

- Chemistry: The letters for the atoms are set in math italics, if used in math mode. I would use a dedicated package (e.g., the example uses `chemmacros`) to get proper typesetting of the chemical formula.
- Numbers and units: The example uses package `siunitx` for the numbers with units. The package takes care of the symbols (degree celsius), the spacing between the number and unit and prevents line breaks before the unit.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\atm{atm}
\begin{document}
How much glucose (\ch{C_6H_{12}O_6}) per liter should be used for an
intravenous solution to match the \SI{7.65}{\atm} at \SI{37}{\celsius}
osmotic pressure of
blood?
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]